# Symfony: Working with a voter per Entity

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I'd like to have a voter per entity.

For example:

CommentController deals with the Comment Entity and uses the CommentVoter to check permissions.

ArticleController deals with the Article Entity and uses the ArticleVoter to check permissions.

And so on....

I thought that the denyAccessUnlessGranted was supposed to check which voter to call, but it's always calling the first one declared in the services.yml:

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('view', $comment);
```

Any idea how to do this ?
I'm on Symfony 2.8

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the supports section of your voter?  This is where the filtering by object type should occur.

Comment: The support method is checking which action of the voter (view, edit, ...) should be used, not which voter.

Comment: So the solution of course is to fix the support method: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html#creating-the-custom-voter

Comment: You didn't even read my reply to your previous comment  --'

Comment: Update your question with the supports section of one of your voters.  Your comment seems to suggest that only actions are being checked, not the object being voted on.

Comment: Ok, here is the final answer to my question: The symfony 2.8 Voter component isn't made to be extended by several voters. So I had to build my own Voting system.